# deleting site collection with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a requirement which is with PowerShell script: when we deleting site collection with PowerShell before deleting we should have a backup copy(bak) in a specified location.

Example:

Remove-SPSite before this action we need to execute the backup-spsite action.

Please suggest me how to achieve the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can use below script.

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell –ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
try
{    
#Location of the Backup Folder  
#This will actually initiate the SPSite backup.
Backup-SPSite -Identity "http://portal/sites/production" -Path "C:\SPBackups\production.bak"

#This will actually initiate the SPSite Remove.
Remove-SPSite -Identity "http://portal/sites/production" -GradualDelete
}
catch
{
#Catch error if  occured.
$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message   
}
```

Comment: Let me try with above code and confirm?

Comment: Working fine with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You can use this code for delete site collection and content db:

**References**: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/06/delete-site-collection-using-powershell-in-sharepoint.html